# find the minimum distance between a point and border of a circle

Tags: circles

I have a circle with radius $R$ and center $(x,y)$ and I have the coordinate of a point; I want to find the minimum path between this point and the border of circle. Here is a picture of what I said:
 [image]

Sorry if the picture is a disaster, I hope you will get the point.

Comment: Draw a line through the point to the center of the circle. It will intersect the circle in two points. The one closest to the point is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to find the distance between the point and the center of the circle and then subtract the radius from it.

Answer (score 1):

Draw radius of the circle from the center to meet the circle at $(a,b)$ and draw a line from $(x,y)$ (your mentioned point outside of the circle) to $(a,b)$. Sum of these two connected lines are minimum if it is straight line, that is, the straight line from $(x,y)$ to $(a,b)$ must include the center as well; so it's the minimum distance!